# how to make style button in top right corner using css

Tags: html, css

I have created on dashboard page which using css style

[image: image1]

But i want to make logout button in top right corner using css like this image using css

[image: image2]

How can we do that logout button in right corner top using css?

I tried to do that but it did not happen
**CSS:**

```
.dashboard {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  /* display: flex; */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dashboard__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.dashboard__btn {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.dashboard div {
  margin-top: 7px;
}
```

the html render code

```
return (
    <div className="dashboard">
      <div className="dashboard__container">
       welcome
        <div>{name}</div>
        <div>{user?.email}</div>
        <button className="dashboard__btn" onClick={logout}>
          Logout
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Any body please help me out???

Comment: can u please add the html code too?

Comment: @GhostOps added please check and help

Comment: Any one idea about that how can we do that using css

Comment: @nehasingh     It's not html but jsx. tag your question properly ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work

```
.dashboard__btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

you can do this I am just not sure if it's the best practice, I am also a beginner,

```
.welcome {   position: absolute; } //in css
```

and

```
<div className="welcome">welcome</div> //in react
```

Comment: yes its work @Meshael

Comment: and please help me one thing how to make welcome in left corner

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwpUA.png i want this type style

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Meshael Could you please suggest and help me out this type style https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwpUA.png

Comment: you can do this I am just not sure if it's the best practice, I am also a beginner, `.welcome {
  position: absolute;
}` and `<div className="welcome">welcome</div>` in react

Comment: ok but i try to make this type https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwpUA.png but not.if  you can help me out its  great help

Comment: I am going to edit the answer

Comment: ok please i want this type https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwpUA.png

Comment: could you please check the answer as answered if it was helpful.

Comment: @Meshaell yes its fine but i want name and email show in center in body part any  idea how can we do that??

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

Just removed some code which does nothing and added `justify-content: space-between;` to the `dashboard__container` and that does the trick

```css
.dashboard {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #3e295a;
}

.dashboard__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #7015b8;
  padding: 1em 20px 1em 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dashboard__btn {
  margin-top: -5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #402958;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard">
  <div class="dashboard__container">
    Welcome 
    <div>{name}</div>
    <div>{user?.email}</div>
    <button class="dashboard__btn" onclick="{logout}">
      Logout
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tell me if its not working...

Comment: yes its work. thanks for help

Comment: @nehasingh consider upvoting if the answer is helpful, and also accept the answer if it does 100% what you want